# Run script on Windows startup without using GP

Tags: windows, active-directory, startup, gpo

There is network with about 50 Windows (servers and clients) machines.
I have some script that needs to be run on those machines' startup.

- Local GPO is problematic because I don't want to go through all these machines and set it.
- Domain GPO is problematic because the script I'm going to run removing the machine from the domain, but I still need it to run after the restart that comes after the domain quit.
- Registry key is problematic because the script needs to run before the user login.

How can I setup that the script will run on startup without set it locally or depended on domain ?

Comment: You haven't really left yourself a lot of options tbh, install a service through domain gp?

Answer (score 1):

Use the best of both worlds.

Use two scripts.

1. You use Domain GP to install a setup script.
2. Your setup script configures Local GP to run your original script.

Would that [have] work[ed] for you?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set something up on startup (before the logon process) by putting an executable in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\BootExecute

See:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897447

Comment: I believe that only works with native applications (not Win32 applications) so is probably not appropriate in this case.

Comment: It's not working for me, I guess it's because at this step of startup it can't use operating environment APIs like Win32.